# How to use Docker Compose without rebuilding images everytime a change is made?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and running an Instance of Saleor using `docker-compose-up` command which builds multiple containers. Everytime I make a change to the source code in any folder, docker starts rebuilding all the images and takes up a lot of time and system resources. Now I've read that this can be overcome by mounting a volume or something but I am not quite sure how to implement it.
Here is what my `docker-compose.yml` looks like.

```
version: '2'

services:
  api:
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    build:
      context: ./saleor
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        STATIC_URL: '/static/'
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - jaeger
    volumes:
      - ./saleor/saleor/:/app/saleor:Z
      - ./saleor/templates/:/app/templates:Z
      - ./saleor/tests/:/app/tests
      # shared volume between worker and api for media
      - saleor-media:/app/media
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file: common.env
    environment:
      - JAEGER_AGENT_HOST=jaeger
      - STOREFRONT_URL=http://localhost:3000/
      - DASHBOARD_URL=http://localhost:9000/

  storefront:
    build:
      context: ./saleor-storefront
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./saleor-storefront/:/app:cached
      - /app/node_modules/
    command: npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0

  dashboard:
    build:
      context: ./saleor-dashboard
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./saleor-dashboard/:/app:cached
      - /app/node_modules/
    command: npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0

  db:
    image: library/postgres:11.1-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    volumes:
      - saleor-db:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=saleor
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=saleor

  redis:
    image: library/redis:5.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    volumes:
      - saleor-redis:/data

  worker:
    build:
      context: ./saleor
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        STATIC_URL: '/static/'
    command: celery -A saleor worker --app=saleor.celeryconf:app --loglevel=info
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    env_file: common.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mailhog
    volumes:
      - ./saleor/saleor/:/app/saleor:Z,cached
      - ./saleor/templates/:/app/templates:Z,cached
      # shared volume between worker and api for media
      - saleor-media:/app/media
    environment:
      - EMAIL_URL=smtp://mailhog:1025

  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one
    ports:
      - "5775:5775/udp"
      - "6831:6831/udp"
      - "6832:6832/udp"
      - "5778:5778"
      - "16686:16686"
      - "14268:14268"
      - "9411:9411"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports: 
      - 1025:1025 # smtp server
      - 8025:8025 # web ui. Visit http://localhost:8025/ to check emails
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier

volumes:
  saleor-db:
    driver: local
  saleor-redis:
    driver: local
  saleor-media:

networks:
  saleor-backend-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

***What changes should be made in order to avoid recompiling all the containers ?***

Here is one of the Dockerfile in the storefront container.

```
FROM node:10 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ARG API_URI
ENV API_URI ${API_URI:-http://localhost:8000/graphql/}
RUN API_URI=${API_URI} npm run build

FROM nginx:stable
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /app/
```

Answer (score 3):

You choose the service you want to build, then docker-compose up only recreate the containers which changed.

```
docker-compose build <service1>  // build only service1
docker-compose up -d             // update only the service which has changed
```

Comment: Might sound childish but I am trying to avoid rebuilding altogether as it takes up a lot of time. I want to be able to view my changes in the browser dynamically after altering the code.

Comment: you can use volume to map the source on your host to your container then you can restart the container or application if needed. If you map a volume with host_source_dir:container_source_dir you can replace the source in the image by your local source

Comment: That sounds like the solution. Can you kindly take a look at my docker-compose.yml file above and point out the changes ?

Comment: Usually the sources are added in the image thanks to the Dockerfile. With only the docker-compose.yml, it is not possible to know where are the source in your containers.

Comment: I've updated my post with a Dockerfile. Can you look into it ?

Comment: You already map your source folder ./saleor-storefront to /app with ./saleor-storefront/:/app:cached. So you just need to restart the container after any change. docker-compose restart storefront.  I think anyway you need to rebuild the image as a restart is not enough as you need to do a npm build.